# Can the Windows 8 Mail app show Gmail's priority inbox?

Tags: windows-8, gmail-imap, windows-store-app

I can't live without Gmail [Priority Inbox](https://mail.google.com/mail/help/intl/en/priority-inbox.html), which right now means I can't live with the Mail app in Windows 8.

Priority inbox essentially filters out messages that aren't important, and displays them in a separate list. The priority inbox list can also be found by searching `in:inbox is:important`. I noticed that in the Gmail API's [extensions to the IMAP protocol](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw) have an option to filter messages by Gmail search commands, so there may be some way to achieve it through that.

What I'd like to do is either have some sort of priority inbox in the Mail app, or alternatively, only download important emails through the Mail app. Is there some way to do this with the mail app? If so, how?

Comment: Is the priority inbox a folder in gmail?

Comment: @PratyushNalam Gmail doesn't really have folders per se.

Comment: Is it one of the folder under [Gmail]?

Comment: @PratyushNalam nope.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to the Priority Inbox

1. Training: I am not aware of anything that will let you up rank e-mails with the exception of Google's own tools
2. The emails: You can access the choices made by going to a folder usually called `[Gmail]`, it will be per category, and will not be amalgamated. For example, you may find a folder called `Important`.

Comment: I looked in the [Gmail] IMAP folder and there's no priority inbox folder there.

Comment: @nhinkle It won't be a single box. it will say things like "Important"

Comment: [This is what the folder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m9XBA.png) under the `[Gmail]` label looks like. No "important" or "priority inbox" or anything like that.

Comment: @nhinkle Sounds like you have no important emails? Can you check if you have any messages tagged high priority? I suspect the sorting kind of functionality you want is not available in desktop clients.

Comment: Definitely not true. If I log in from the Gmail web interface, all of my important mail is labeled as such. Did you actually test this method?

Comment: @nhinkle I see my emails automatically appear in the important email box though the Windows 8 client and the K9 android mail client. The kind of single box you want is not available.